# I am trying to push to Heroku, but it says I have bad fingerprint

Tags: git, heroku, ssh

!  Your key with fingerprint XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX is not authorized to access app

I have already pushed the new key to the server, but it is not allowing me to access the server.  I have two heroku accounts as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that you can switch accounts from:

http://martyhaught.com/articles/2010/12/14/managing-multiple-heroku-accounts/

This addon is great and flawless ( just make sure you make separate ssh keys for each Heroku Account ).

I hope this help other people :)

Answer (score 0):

Generate an SSH key if you don't already have one, and upload it to Heroku with `heroku keys:add`.

Useful link: [Managing Your SSH Keys for Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys#adding_keys_to_heroku).